# Windows 10で、自作のプログラムを既定のアプリ一覧に表示させたい

Tags: c++, windows-10

Windows 10で、http,httpsプロトコルで開くソフトを作成したいのですが、それにあたって、作成したソフト(.exe)をWindowsの既定のアプリ(ブラウザ)一覧にプログラムを登録する方法がわかりません。

[image: このアプリ一覧に表示させたい]
↑のアプリ一覧に表示させたい

レジストリの書き換え等試しましたがやり方が悪いのか規定のブラウザがリセットされてしまいました。

開発環境は以下です
・OS:Windows 10 1903
・使用言語:C++
・コンパイラ:gcc(minGW-w64)

Comment: その自作のプログラムは、どのような機能を持つアプリなのですか？

Comment: 現時点では引数として入力された値をテキストファイルに保存する。
というだけの至って単純なプログラムです。

Comment: それって、Windowsのどんなアプリと同じ機能なのですか？
　Firefox, Internet Explorer, Edgeが既定のアプリの候補として並んでいるのは、全部Webブラウザという共通した機能を持っているからです。
　NetscapeもWebブラウザの既定のアプリになり得ますが、WordやExcelがWebブラウザの既定のアプリになることはあり得ません、何故ならWordやExcelにWebブラウザの機能を持たないからです。

Comment: ブラウザであろうとそうでなかろうと、何らかの方法で既定のアプリとして設定はできるはずです。
実際、現在でも拡張子ごとであればたとえ全く無関係なアプリでも直接既定のアプリを選択できます(例えば.mp3を開く既定のアプリをメモ帳にする等)し、Windows 7ではプロトコルなどでも同様にできました。
おそらく、このリストに表示されるソフトはインストール時に何かしらの動作をしていると思うのですが。

Comment: もしかしたら、この記事が参考になるかも。[windows10　既定のアプリ　アプリを選ぶに表示されない場合](https://ameblo.jp/gyouseisyosi-ogawa/entry-12141159671.html)

Comment: 記事の方法を試しましたが、Windows 10のビルドが違うためか、記事のような画面へは遷移せず、一部のアプリしか既定のアプリとして設定できないという状態です。
また、Google Chromeをインストールし、既定のブラウザをChromeにした上でchrome.exeを自作プログラムに置き換えた場合は当然ながら動作しました

Comment: あるいはこれらの記事？ [Windows10で関連付け出来ない場合 (バージョン1803)](https://pc-more.fimplex.com/article/can_not_associate_windows10/), [URI に応じた既定のアプリの起動](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app), [予約済みのファイルと URI スキーム名](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/uwp/launch-resume/reserved-uri-scheme-names), [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)), [カスタム ブラウザ プロトコルを使用してアプリケーションを起動する](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/ja/articles/219031308)